# I can't seem to get my grand Total to calculate correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

When I run this query below,

```
SELECT clientid, 
       CASE WHEN D.ccode = '-1' Then 'Did Not Show' ELSE D.ccode End ccode,  
       ca, 
       ot, 
       bw, 
       cshT, 
       dc, 
       dte, 
       approv 
  FROM dbo.emC D 
 WHERE year(dte) = year(getdate())
```

I get the correct results.

It is correct result because ccode shows 'Did Not Show' when the value on the db is '-1'

However, when I do a UNION ALL so I can get total for each column, I get the results but then 'Did Not Show' is no longer visible when valye for ccode is '-1'.

There are over 1000 records with valuye of '-1'.

Can someone please help?

Here is the entire code with UNION.

```
SELECT clientid, 
CASE WHEN D.ccode = '-1' Then 'Did Not Show' ELSE D.ccode End ccode,  
ca, 
ot, 
bw, 
cshT, 
dc, 
dte, 
approv 
FROM dbo.emC D WhERE year(dte) = year(getdate())
UNION ALL   
SELECT 'Total',
 '', 
 SUM(D.ca), 
 SUM(D.ot), 
 SUM(D.bw), 
 SUM(D.cshT),
'',
'',
'' 
  FROM emC D 
 WHERE YEAR(dte)='2011'
```

I also tried using ROLLUP but the real issue here is that I can't get the 'Did Not Show' text to display when ccode value is -1

```
ClientID        CCODE           ot      ca      bw      cshT
019692  CF001           0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00   0.00   
019692  CH503           0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00   0.00
010487  AC407           0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00   0.00
028108  CH540           0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00   0.00
028108  GS925           0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00   0.00
001038  AC428           0.00    0.00    3.00    0.00   0.00
028561  Did Not Show        0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00
016884  Did Not Show        0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00
05184   CF001           0.00    0.00    4.50    0.00   0.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The union actually worked. The only problem was that I was querying the wrong table which didn't have any value of '-1'.

So, essentially, I was right that UNION had nothing to do with why the query didn't work. It would have worked if I had the value I was using CASE statement against.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because, each SQL statement within the UNION ALL query must have the same number of fields in the result sets with similar data types. Quoted from MSDN:

> The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two
>   queries by using UNION:
>
> - The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all    queries.
> - The data types must be compatible

Now, your 'Did not show' output, changes the column data type. Try creating a pseudo column in both the queries and have a two column output, or else, give the output for when the case is not found as a numerical value.

EDIT: ccode is of nvarchar(50) type. But when you output 'Did not show', it is of text type, and there occurs a data type mismatch. One may wonder that nvarchar should be able to handle text, but technically it is a datatype mismatch, and it will create such runtime issues. Or atleast this is what I know according to my understanding..

Comment: The data type didn't change though. ccode is of nvarchar(50). Perhaps, I misse your point. An example would be great. Thanks for your time and assistance.

Comment: Please state the exact column column structure for the columns that will be outputted by both the queries.

Comment: I have updated the post above with sample layout. Sorry, they shifted left. Thank you very much. I really, appreciate your help.